# Cyclic Subgroups and General Linear Group

Tags: group-theory

Show that for a constant $\theta$

$$H = \bigg\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
 cos n \theta & -sin n \theta \\
 sin n \theta & cos n \theta
\end{array} \right) \Bigg| \textit{n} \in \mathbb{Z} \bigg\}$$

is a cyclic subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{R}).$ Do you think $H$ is finite?

Comment: I think H is finite. I just don't know how to show that H is a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: I know that the general linear group is the set of all n x n matrices such that  the matrices are invertible under matrix multiplication.

Comment: $\text{cyclic} \iff \text{generated by a single element}$. What seems like a good guess for a generator, that you could confirm/deny with algebra?

Comment: The identity matrix?

Comment: OK, so you can test that conjecture with algebra, by seeing what elements you get by computing successive powers of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos n\theta & -\sin n\theta \\ \sin n\theta & \cos n\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos m\theta & -\sin m\theta \\ \sin m\theta & \cos m\theta\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos (n+m)\theta & -\sin (n+m)\theta \\ \sin (n+m)\theta & \cos (n+m)\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$

You can conclude that $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos n\theta & -\sin n\theta \\ \sin n\theta & \cos n\theta\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}^n.$$